# Prolog for sets (lists)

Tags: list, prolog, artificial-intelligence

I'm learning prolog through youtube videos and I'm struggling a lot with lists. I'm trying to write  a  predicate  overlap(A,B)  that will find out if A and B have any common elements. Which I'm able to do but how can I use this overlap(A,B) predicate to define another predicate disjoint(S1, S2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no overlap between `S1`and `S2` then `S1`and `S2` are disjoint:

```
disjoint(S1,S2) :- \+ overlap(S1,S2).
```

Comment: Your answer assumes the OP correctly implemented overlap/2. For the OP, see: [What is wrong with intersection/3 and friends?](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=intersection/3)

Comment: This was such a simple solution that I missed. Thanks!